Minimum-weight bipartite matching on the unit interval
This is related to another question I just asked 1, after running some experiments.  Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent uniform sets of points in the unit interval, with $|X| = 2|Y|$.  By running large experiments with $|X|$ up to 2000, it appears that the expected cost of the minimum-weight bipartite matching that pairs every element in $Y$ with something in $X$ (where the cost between two points is simply the absolute value of their difference) is bounded above by $0.5$, independent of $|X|$.  Is it known why would this would be the case?  It's surprising because it is known that when $|X|=|Y|$, the cost scales proportionally to $\sqrt{|X|}$.
UPDATE:  I ran a bunch of experiments for $|X|\in\{250,500,1000\}$ and I set $|Y|=\alpha|X|$ for $0<\alpha\leq0.75$ (so my original question concerns the case $\alpha=0.5$) and it looks like the expected matching cost is still bounded independently of $|X|$.  In fact for $\alpha\leq 0.5$ I would say the cost of the matching is equal to $\alpha$!

1 Minimum weight maximum matching in the unit interval

How is the cost of the minimum-weight bipartite matching defined?

@IosifPinelis sorry, absolute value between the two points (Euclidean distance)

What do you mean by "bounded above by 0.5"?  Are you running random trials to select all the points $X$ and $Y$ using a uniform distribution?  If so, what is the cost if all of the $X$ points end up less than 0.1 and all of the $Y$ points end up greater than 0.9?  Are you measuring the expected cost?  Please give more details.

@user65023 sorry, expected distance.  Edited accordingly, thank you!
